# Не видно елементов под видео

Tags: html, css

У меня есть код, который показывает видео. В том видео я хочу сделать меню, но моего меню не видно. Как сделать чтобы меню было над видео? В чем моя ошибка? Спасибо большое

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="background-video">
    <video src="Star%20-%206962.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
    <div class="menu-content">
        <div><a href="#">One</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">One</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">One</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">One</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">One</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.background-video{
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.background-video video{
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
object-fit: cover;
z-index: 1;
}

.menu-content{
z-index: 2;
}

a{
color: red
}
```

Comment: Для `menu-content` задайте `position: absolute; top: 0;`

Comment: Задай `.menu-content: position: relative;`